# Materialize SideNav, can it be more than one on a single page?

Tags: jquery, html, materialize

I want to use multiple sidenavs on the same page, I already made the HTML structure:

```
<li class="top_icons">
            <a href="#" data-activates="slide-member" class="open_slide">Member</a>

        </li>
        <li class="top_icons">
            <a href="#" data-activates="slide-language" class="open_slide">Language</a>
        </li>
        <li class="top_icons">
            <a href="#" data-activates="slide-search" class="open_slide">Search</a>
        </li>
        <li class="top_icons">
            <a href="#" data-activates="slide-cart" class="open_slide open_cart">Cart</a>
        </li>

<!-- # 1 -->
<div id="slide-member" class="side-nav">
Member
<div>
<!-- # 2 -->
<div id="slide-language" class="side-nav">
 Member
<div>
<!-- # 3 -->
<div id="slide-search" class="side-nav">
Member
<div>
<!-- # 4 -->
<div id="slide-cart" class="side-nav">
 Member
<div>
```

The problem is that when any of the 4 sidenavs is active, and another one is called. The second when opens it is above/bellow the previous one. How to close the previous sidenav when a new one is called? So that on the page will always be active only one sidenav.

Thank you!

Comment: In this documentation link http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html it is shown how to programatically close the sidebar. you can use this technique to close sidebar

Comment: You can add separate classes for each sidenav alongwith main class `sidenav`. 
`e.g. <ul id="slide-out-right" class="sidenav sidenav-right">`. Then each of them can be controlled using their specific class.